# Can max_concurrent_requests be greater than 80 for larger instance classes (F4 and above)

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

**Prototype mode :**

My app.yaml in prototype mode has the following - this works and scales fine

```
automatic_scaling:
  instance_class: f1 
  max_concurrent_requests: 80
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.9
```

**Production Mode**

I want to move to **F4 or above** instance classes in production.

> However, `max_concurrent_requests` can take only max value as 80.
>
> Should `max_concurrent_requests` have higher value for larger instances since they can handle more requests/second ?

I do not want to spin up extra instances while using higher instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[80 is the maximum](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/appref#scaling_elements).

However, if individual requests return faster on the higher instance class, then each instance will handle more requests than a lower instance class would, and you'll spin up fewer total instances with same "maximum_concurrent_requests" value.

This isn't purely a function of the instance class size, it depends on what sort of actions you are taking in response to a request. For example, if you are performing API requests, increasing the instance class may not change the response time at all, since you might be limited by network or 3rd party performance.

Additionally, you can set target_throughput_utilization and target_cpu_utilization to numbers higher than 0.6 (the default) to increase the workload of each instance and decrease the number of new instances being spawned, but this will only get you so far.

Ultimately, if you want to spin up fewer instances, you need to speed up the handling of individual requests, whether that involves increasing the instance size, or other optimisation, depends on your application.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess I've to know how much a instance class is capable of handling. It is simple web app with SSR frontend.